# Parse Date "01/01/2016 Fri"

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to parse a date in JavaScript, but the particular format is giving me fits. I have exported data from my credit card company and the format of the date field is not compatible with `Date.parse` or `moment().isValid()`.

E.g.

```
Date.parse("01/01/2016  Fri") // NaN
moment("01/01/2016  Fri") // false
```

I'm not sure if I should do something with a RegEx `.test()` or `.matches()` because this is being used for a CSV import utility where dates may be in different formats. I was surprised the utility functions above didn't work.

Comment: If the day of the week is not important you can trim the `  Fri` leaving a valid date string. The day of week can always be re-calculated or `split` so that it is still accessible.

Comment: how many date formats?could you list all the formats in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [in the Moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to see how to parse a date in any format. The first argument is the date string, the second is the format string. Alphanumeric characters are ignored, so you don't need to worry about slashes vs. dashes.

`moment("01/01/2016 Fri", "MM-DD-YYYY ddd)`

Comment: "Alpha*numeric*" means numbers also

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 is right, and the docs actually say that non-alphanumeric characters are ignored. 'ddd' should let you parse the day of week as part of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Mozilla MDN on Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> The parse() method takes a date string (such as "Dec 25, 1995") and
>   returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00
>   UTC. This function is useful for setting date values based on string
>   values, for example in conjunction with the setTime() method and the
>   Date object.
>
> Given a string representing a time, parse() returns the time value. It
>   accepts the RFC2822 / IETF date syntax (RFC2822 Section 3.3), e.g.
>   "Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT". It understands the continental US
>   time zone abbreviations, but for general use, use a time zone offset,
>   for example, "Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 +0430" (4 hours, 30 minutes
>   east of the Greenwich meridian).

From this, it looks like your problem is that you're giving the date in the improper format:

> It
>   accepts the RFC2822 / IETF date syntax (RFC2822 Section 3.3), e.g.
>   "Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT".

Check this out:

> Invalid values in date strings not recognized as ISO format as defined by ECMA-262 may or may not result in NaN, depending on the browser and values provided, e.g.:

```
// Non-ISO string with invalid date values
new Date('23/25/2014');
```

TL;DR - you're passing the values in a format that is not recognized, which is why it's returning NaN.

Try this source for Regexes for dates: [Regexlib.com](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). The site is a little out of date, but the info is great. It has tons of different Regexes for different date formats.

Comment: You seem to have not quoted the most important part: "***It is not recommended to use Date.parse…***".